# retornar valores de un fragment B a un fragment A

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estoy generando una app que tiene dos fragmentos, el cual muestra una actividad principal la cual lleva a un segundo fragment en el cual es un tipo formulario el cual obtiene un textView y al seleccionar enviar debe de regresar al fragment B y ejecutar un Toast para mostrar la informacion, a continuacion muestro como obtengo los datos del textView, y lo mando a una Interface [image: fragmento donde obtengo el resultado del edit Text]

Es enviando a la interfaz que lleva por nombre TrazarRuta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los envio a la activity dueña de los fragmentos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y los recibo en el Fragment A de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que me arroja un excepción al ejecutar la app, me menciona lo siguiente.

```
-21 14:57:58.374 9667-9667/com.example.rastreosgps.taxi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rastreosgps.taxi, PID: 9667
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=409716175, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.rastreosgps.taxi/com.example.rastreosgps.taxi.MainActivityMaps}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.rastreosgps.taxi.FragmentMap.recibir(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.rastreosgps.taxi.FragmentMap.recibir(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.rastreosgps.taxi.MainActivityMaps.enviarDatos(MainActivityMaps.java:20)
    at com.example.rastreosgps.taxi.FragmentDestino$1.onPlaceSelected(FragmentDestino.java:176)
    at com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment.onActivityResult(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@2.4.0:100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$9.onActivityResult(FragmentManager.java:2905)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$9.onActivityResult(FragmentManager.java:2885)
    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:377)
    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.java:336)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:624)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta para colocar el código como texto. Te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: te agradezcom ahora mismo lo edito